# MYSQL - AVG Function with $ sign

Tags: mysql

i need to make a query that shows the average of each employee salary and it needs to be formatted with the $ sign. this is what i have and where im stuck at, any feedback?

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS 'Employee Full Name',
AirportName, CONCAT('$',FORMAT(Salary,2)) AS 'Average Salary', 
MobileNumber, Email
FROM employees GROUP BY FirstName;
```

also when i add the AVG(salary) where the format is, it only shows one employee salary and not all of them

Comment: Won't the average salary of all employees be the same.. or can an employee have more than 1 salary?

Comment: The query is wrong until `FirstName` is primary key of `employees` table. *a query that shows the average of each employee salary* Average salary for one employee makes no sense... maybe you need in average salary over all employees? if so why you 're surprised that this is one single value? PS. Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: 8.0.21 MySQL Community Server is the version and the question that is being asked is "Show the average salary of each employee." unless Im misinterpreting that then should'nt it be for each employee?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this instead:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS `Employee Full Name`,
  AirportName,
  mobilenumber,
  email,
  CONCAT('$',FORMAT(avg(Salary),2)) AS `Average Salary`
FROM employees
GROUP BY
  CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName),
  AirportName,
  mobilenumber,
  email;
```

**Example**

```
create table employees (
  firstname text,
  lastname text,
  airportname text,
  mobilenumber text,
  email text,
  salary decimal(10,2)
);
insert into employees values 
('matt', 'jensen', 'airport-a', '111', 'a@b.com', 100.50),
('matt', 'jensen', 'airport-a', '111', 'a@b.com', 200.50),
('pinny', 'donna', 'airport-b', '222', 'c@d.com', 50.50),
('pinny', 'donna', 'airport-b', '222', 'c@d.com', 350.50),
('golo', 'prada', 'airport-a', '333', 'z@x.com', 10.50);
```

**Query's result**

> ```
> Employee Full Name | AirportName | mobilenumber | email   | Average Salary
> :----------------- | :---------- | :----------- | :------ | :-------------
> golo prada         | airport-a   | 333          | z@x.com | $10.50        
> matt jensen        | airport-a   | 111          | a@b.com | $150.50       
> pinny donna        | airport-b   | 222          | c@d.com | $200.50
> ```

See this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3030e55183dd1bbd769a9567f48ab282

**Explanation**

Include all your non-statistics columns in your group by. Doing so, you are telling the database that for a unique combination of full name, airport, cell and email, you want average salary.

Your `concat` idea seems to be just fine. You'd just have to make sure you are concatenating `$` with formatted average salary. Basically, you were on the right track.

Comment: The query still doesn't give me the average for each employee salary, would there have to be sub query to get that result?

Comment: Without seeing your data, it will be hard to tell what's wrong. Do this: Go to https://dbfiddle.uk/, create a table there, add your data and add a simple select statement like `select * from employees`. Run it. Post the URL and update your question with the expected result. I am sure we can help you out.

Comment: @vin15 do you need any further help on this question?